# onfullscreenchange DOM event

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, fullscreen

as the title reads, I'd like to know what is the most reliable way to trigger an event when the Browser(s) enters/leaves in/out the fullscreen mode.

**note :** I'm not asking how to fullscreen the current page, I just want to know whether or not there is a way to queue some tasks if the user, for example, press F11 or any other related fullscreen-entering keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`screen.width` and `screen.height` tell you the user's screen resolution, so try this:

```
var fullscreen;
function onfullscreenchange(full) {
    ...
}

// You might want to use addEventListener and its equivalents instead
window.onresize = function () {
    if (window.outerWidth === screen.width && window.outerHeight === screen.height) {
        if (!fullscreen) {
            fullscreen = true;
            onfullscreenchange(true);
        }
    } else {
        if (fullscreen) {
            fullscreen = false;
            onfullscreenchange(false);
    }
};
```

I'm aware this isn't the cleanest or most robust way of doing all this, but hopefully it gives you an idea. Notably, IE<9 needs a different approach for determining the window size, so I'll leave you to look that up.

Comment: +1 Thats what i was thinking about ... was just going to put some code together ...like you say not 100% reliable but a great starting point ...

Comment: Also, this will fail if the user has multiple monitors... and there's no way of detecting this reliably

Comment: thanks, however I encounter some troubles with the resizing event in Firefox, that is why I never use it, too bad it looks great.
I finally use John Resig's addEvent function and look up the keyCode when the user press a key on his keyboard.

Comment: @Oddant what happens if the user uses the mouse to trigger full screen ?

Comment: @ManseUK yes that's true but I assume more than 90% of them will trigger the key (I display a message on the page leading them to press F11)

Comment: Just tested it in Firefox and it worked fine for me. The event fired multiple times, but that can easily be remedied.

Comment: @NathanMacInnes I didn't use the attribute but instead the function to add an event to the window (that's probably why it was boggling my browser) now it works. anyway `window.onresize = fn` is that reliable ?

Comment: Yes, that will work across all browsers. The reason it's not the favoured approach is because you can't add more than one function to `window.onresize` at a time. Most people tend to do `if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('resize', fn, false); } else if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onresize', fn); } else { window.onresize = fn; }`.

Answer (score 9):

I was working with this event when I stumble with this question, I want to share what I learn about it even though it won't solve this question. The **onfullscreenchange** event is now supported with prefixes [by modern desktop browsers and Chrome for Android](http://caniuse.com/#search=Full%20Screen%20API), but there are some things to have in mind:

- This event won't trigger when the window goes fullscreen, I know it sounds weird, but it seems to be intended only for the document and its elements. So if an element of a document goes fullscreen the event will trigger, but when a keyboard shortcut is used to make your browser fullscreen it won't.
- In **Chrome** and **Safari** a function can subscribe to this event either by defining the document method `document.onwebkitfullscreenchange = myFunc;` or by defining the element method `myElem.onwebkitfullscreenchange = myFunc;`, also you can use addEventListener `myElem.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", myFunc);`. In **IE** and **Firefox** the event will work **only if the method is defined in the document** and using **addEventListener won't trigger the event**.

Here's a [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/a-guerrero/pen/mVQYVx?editors=0010) of this event, more info in [MDN Using fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

---

**Update**. From MDN web docs:

> For the moment not all browsers are implementing the unprefixed version of the API (for vendor agnostic access to the Fullscreen API you can use [Fscreen](https://github.com/rafrex/fscreen)).

Comment: The Codepen Demo helped me out. It's a shame so much work is needed to get to this trivial event.

Comment: At the time of this writing, on Safari desktop v13.1, the `fullscreenchange`event is still not supported (tested on the full screen element and the `document` element), nor the `onfullscreenchange` listener: you need to set the `onwebkitfullscreenchange` listener or listen to the `webkitfullscreenchange` event.

Comment: And as far as Edge is concerned, the `onwebkitfullscreenchange` listener should be used, and regarding Internet Explorer v10 and v11, the `onmsfullscreenchange` listener.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly other approach using a `media query` and a fallback to the `window.document.fullscreenElement`.

This works on Chrome whether it's a click/touch event or the <kbd>F11</kbd> key being pressed.

```
function fullscreenEvent(fullscreen) {
    ...
}

window.onresize = function () {
    if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: fullscreen)').matches ||
    window.document.fullscreenElement) {
       fullscreenEvent(true);
    } else {
       fullscreenEvent(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Even works in Angular (14) : install the event handler in the constructor (so it is only installed once) and create a function `isFullScreen` returning the boolean expression in `if` statement. THen in your HTML-template use e.g. `*ngIf="isFullScreen()"` to toggle icons.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin available for jQuery](https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen) ( i know your not using jQuery ) ..... what it does is listen to the keys pressed on the window - so it listens for F11 being pressed etc ... Not the greatest solution but one that might work

Short of that I think you are stumped ...

A thought ...

I just stumbled across this page -> http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

JavaScript can detect the size of the screen using screen.width / screen.height ... perhaps use the resize event to see if the browser matches the screen size ie fullscreen ?

@Nathans answer is **exactly** what i was talking about ...

Comment: thanks mister, you're right I'm not using jQuery :)
I prefer the addEvent function which is light and consistent in modern browsers, anyway as a matter of fact , 'keyup' on the window element in IE doesn't seem to be recognized, any idea ?

Comment: @Oddant 'keyup' = when the key is released

Answer (score 0):

There is a [proposed Fullscreen API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI#Proposed_Specification) for Javascript, which would allow you to hook into the `onfullscreenchange` event.

However, I 'm not very optimistic with regards to browser support at this point in time.

Comment: thanks I already saw that though, but it's not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

how about using this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen)

yes, I know there might be an pure js way, but this is very easy.