# Detecting Event change in fullscreen mode Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to write an event handler that detects whether a video player I have is in fullscreen or 'regular' mode.

I have tried using

```
 document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", myfunc, false);
```

but this doesn't work in IE, I have implemnted the same thing for firefox and chrome using webkitfullscreenchange and mozfullscreenchange event. Is there any other event I can use in IE for this? Or another way of doing this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to say, the HTML5 Full Screen API isn't supported in IE10, so I doubt anything but a hack will work. http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have jQuery, so use it:

```
var screen_change_events = "webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange";
$(document).on(screen_change_events, function () {

});
```

(`addEventListener` isn't supported in versions earlier than IE 9 anyways)

At the same time, it doesn't look like full screen is supported in any version of IE:

- http://caniuse.com/fullscreen

MDN Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode

Here's a possible hack around it:

- [onfullscreenchange DOM event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358196/onfullscreenchange-dom-event)

Comment: yes I saw this hack, but I was just wondering if there was a more standard way to achieve this, thanks!

Comment: @lboyel Well yeah, with the Fullscreen API, but that isn't supported in any IE and many browsers. There isn't anything that can emulate it. There may be jQuery plugins or something, but all they do is make it easier to work with the API. If the API isn't supported in the browser, I'd say that hack is the only/best option.

Comment: @Ian this will not work on IE11 or later, for IE11 and later, add 'MSFullscreenChange' to screen_change_events

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin named [jquery-fullscreen](https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen) that will do exactly what you want. Until the Fullscreen-API standard has crystallized this is probably the best option.

You can also use the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) fullscreen-api check and shim it if the browser doesn't support it by firing the event yourself (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358196/onfullscreenchange-dom-event) for a detection method)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer and if applicable upvote the answer and alternative answers. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I tried this with IE11, but this doesn't work. I also tried with "MSFullscreenChange", but its not working. Is there any other way to do this?