# IE11 doesn't listen to MSFullscreenChange event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to use fullscreen in IE11 using Bigscreen.js.
But IE11 doesnt listen to "MSFullscreenChange" event.

```
document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", function () {
     if (document.msFullscreenElement != null) {
         console.info("Went full screen");
     } else {
         console.info("Exited full screen");              
     }
});
```

Putting this in console, it prints nothing on fullscreen.
What is the alternate way to detect this event?

Comment: Would this be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069548/detecting-event-change-in-fullscreen-mode-internet-explorer

Comment: That hack doesnt work with IE11

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Microsoft documentation is wrong.

I'm testing against IE11 and it doesn't have the `MSFullscreenChange` event listener. Instead, it has the `onmsfullscreenchange` event handler.

So, just change this and your code should work.

Comment: Strange, for me `MSFullscreenChange` works in IE11 (version 11.165.17134.0, update 11.0.75) and `msfullscreenchange` doesn't work.

Comment: Same for me, `MSFullscreenChange` works in IE11, so I had to downvote your answer, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in [my word game](https://wordsbyfarber.com), the `MSFullscreenChange` listener was not called in Internet Explorer 11:

[image: ie11 screenshot]

To fix the problem I had to attach the listener to the `document` instead of the DOM element (`#fullDiv` in my case). Even though all the other listeners where attached to the DOM element going fullscreen:

```
var domElem = document.getElementById('fullDiv');

domElem.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', updateFullCheck);
domElem.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', updateFullCheck);
domElem.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', updateFullCheck);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', updateFullCheck); // IE 11
```

Below is my complete code working in IE11, Edge, Safari/MacOS, Chrome, Firefox, Opera:

```
'use strict';

function isFullscreenEnabled() {
    return  document.fullscreenEnabled || 
            document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || 
            document.mozFullScreenEnabled || 
            document.msFullscreenEnabled;
}

function getFullscreenElement() {
    return  document.fullscreenElement || 
            document.webkitFullscreenElement || 
            document.mozFullScreenElement || 
            document.msFullscreenElement;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (isFullscreenEnabled()) {
        function updateFullCheck() {
            if (getFullscreenElement()) {
                $('#fullCheck').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
                $('#leftDiv').css('padding', '24px 0 24px 24px');
                $('#rightDiv').css('padding', '24px 24px 24px 0');
            } else {
                $('#fullCheck').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
                $('#leftDiv').css('padding', '0');
                $('#rightDiv').css('padding', '0');
            }
        }

        var domElem = document.getElementById('fullDiv');

        domElem.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', updateFullCheck);
        domElem.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', updateFullCheck);
        domElem.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', updateFullCheck);
        document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', updateFullCheck); // IE 11

        $('#fullCheck').checkboxradio().click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            
            if (getFullscreenElement()) {
                if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                    document.exitFullscreen();
                } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                    document.msExitFullscreen();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (domElem.requestFullscreen) {
                        domElem.requestFullscreen();
                    } else if (domElem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                        domElem.mozRequestFullScreen();
                    } else if (domElem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                        domElem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                    } else if (domElem.msRequestFullscreen) {
                        domElem.msRequestFullscreen();
                    }
                }
            }).checkboxradio('enable');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I navigate to http://brad.is/coding/BigScreen/, launch F12 Developer Tools, paste your script into the console, and click the “Run script” button, clicking the demo image displays the "Went full screen" message in the console as expected.

When pasting multiline scripts in the console, you have to click the “Run script” button or press Ctrl + Enter to actually submit the script for execution. Just pressing the Enter key inserts a newline in the script. Alternatively, you can change the script to be single-line. In this case, pressing the Enter key will submit the script for execution.

Disclosure: I am on the team that worked on Microsoft's implementation of the Fullscreen API.