# IE 11 not listening to MSFullscreenChange

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

IE 11 does not seem to be recognizing MSFullscreenChange. I have this code in the script:

```
document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", function () {
        if (document.msFullscreenElement != null) {
            console.info("Went full screen");
        } else {
            console.info("Exited full screen");
        }
});
```

In other words, I'm using the exact code shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn312066.aspx) on Microsoft's own site, but nothing's being printed out in the console, and I know fullscreen is enabled.

I also noticed I'm getting the SEC7118 message: XMLHttpRequest for https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/qywzeXowktA?v=2&alt=json required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). That wouldn't be affecting it, would it?

Comment: How do you make the element goes full screen?

Comment: By clicking on a fullscreen button. I have similar events set up for the other browsers, using their respective prefixes, and those work just fine. It's just IE that isn't agreeing with it.

Comment: You mean by using the full screen API right? Can you post your repro on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I can't try it myself (no windows) but would be interested to find out if the eventname might have been lowercased at some point? I.e. does "msfullscreenchange" work? I ask because that would be consistent with other browsers, which use e.g. "webkitfullscreenchange" and "mozfullscreenchange". For what it's worth the (future) standard will likely be "fullscreenchange". [source](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#rendering)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IE11 doesn't listen to MSFullscreenChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475597/ie11-doesnt-listen-to-msfullscreenchange-event)